# Restart camera service

Tags: cyanogenmod, camera, reboot, zte-racer

I have a smartphone which the camera doesn't work very well with CyanogenMod.

Sometimes (and very often), after taking some picture the camera stops working until I restart the phone.

When I try to open it, it just says "Cannot connect to camera".

I'd like to know if there are some way to "restart" the camera service, or something like that, because it's very annoying to be obligated to restart the phone everytime it stops working.

If that's somehow useful, I have a modified version of CyanogenMod 7 installed.

Comment: What is your device?

Comment: It's ZTE Racer. The problem is that the camera was modified by the carrier that sold it.

Comment: Might be best to check over on [Modaco's ZTE Racer Forum](http://www.modaco.com/forum/454-zte-racer-racermodacocom/) Very likely the kernel has got a unstable driver for camera capture... head over there and you might find the answer :)

Comment: @DielsonSales Have you managed to find a solution to this problem in the end ?

Comment: No, the only way to get the camera to work properly was coming back to the original version of Android.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is in the kernel driver, as t0mm13b suggests, then only resetting the kernel driver will help. There *might* be a hacky way to achieve this with `rmmod` from the command line, if the device is rooted and that driver was built as a module in that ROM. I wouldn't recommend it. Restarting the phone is probably the only way to reset the driver.